# insert data to hbase

Tags: php, hbase, thrift, stargate

I am trying to insert the data to hbase table wth one cloumn family info with column keys name,age..

in table hbase format should be like this

```
row         column+cell
1           column=info:name timestamp=--- value=vani
2           column=info name timestamp=--- value=veena
```

.. the above this be the format..
 then I am using THrift API with hbase +php..

Now I have to write php code for above data insertion to hbase table

plz can anyone tel me.. how to do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use something like this:

```
// get HbaseClient
$client = <your code>;

$mutation =new Mutation(array("column" => "info:name", "value" => "vani"));
$client->mutateRow("table_name", $row_key = 1, array($mutation));

$mutation =new Mutation(array("column" => "info:name", "value" => "veena"));
$client->mutateRow("table_name", $row_key = 2, array($mutation));
```

You need to get client before using mutations, because client includes files needed for mutations and many other;

You can also mutate multiple rows at one time using $client->mutateRows() function and batch mutations

http://hbase.apache.org/apidocs/org/apache/hadoop/hbase/thrift/doc-files/Hbase.html

Answer (score 1):

According to [Hbase FAQ](http://wiki.apache.org/hadoop/Hbase/FAQ#A8) which further points to [Hbase homepage](http://wiki.apache.org/hadoop/Hbase) there exist two methods to communicate with Hbase using PHP: [Thrift](http://wiki.apache.org/hadoop/Hbase/ThriftApi) and [Stargate](http://wiki.apache.org/hadoop/Hbase/Stargate).

These articles may be of help.

- http://chanian.com/2010/05/13/thrift-tutorial-a-php-client/
- http://thrift.apache.org/

Comment: hi.. but how to insert data in php to hbase?? I m using thrift API but i cnt insert the data from front end using php. I hv to inert dynamically everytime!.Plz suggest me ur answer